# My object is getting wrecked in the transfer from activity to activity, using Parcelable, in Android Studio

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, parcelable

To give you a little context, I try to pass my 'match' object from the GamesBottomActivity to the GameActionsActivity. My Match model is implementing Parcelable and I have well implemented the required methods from the interface. Here it is.

```
public class Match  implements Parcelable {

    // Attributes
    private int id;
    private String local ;
    private int score_local ;
    private String visitor;
    private int score_visitor ;

    // private DateTime date;
    private String arena;

    // Constructor
    public Match(JSONObject recipesJson) throws JSONException {
        this.id = recipesJson.getInt("id");
        this.local = recipesJson.getString("local");
        this.score_local = recipesJson.getInt("score_local");
        this.visitor = recipesJson.getString("visitor");
        this.score_visitor = recipesJson.getInt("score_visitor");
        //this.date = recipesJson.getString("date");
        this.arena = recipesJson.getString("arena");
    }

    // Constructor ++
    public Match(int id, String local, String visitor, int score_local, int score_visitor, String arena) {
        this.id = id;
        this.local = local;
        this.score_local = score_local;
        this.visitor = visitor;
        this.score_visitor = score_visitor;
        this.arena = arena;
    }


    // Getters
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getLocal() {
        return local;
    }
    public String getVisitor() {
        return visitor;
    }
    public String getArena() {
        return arena;
    }
    public int getLocalScore() { return score_local;}
    public int getVisitorScore() { return score_visitor;}

    /*
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    */

    // Update function




    protected Match(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readInt();
        local = in.readString();
        visitor = in.readString();
        arena = in.readString();
        //date = in.readString();
        score_local = in.readInt();
        score_visitor = in.readInt();
    }

    public static final Creator<Match> CREATOR = new Creator<Match>() {
        @Override
        public Match createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Match(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Match[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Match[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeInt(id);
        parcel.writeString(local);
        parcel.writeInt(score_local);
        parcel.writeString(visitor);
        parcel.writeInt(score_visitor);
        parcel.writeString(arena);
        //parcel.writeInt(date);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{ " +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", arena='" + arena + '\'' +
                ", local ='" + local + '\'' +
                ", local score ='" + score_local + '\'' +
                ", visitor ='" + visitor +'\''+
                ", visitor score ='" + score_local+'}';

    }

}
```

Code I'm using to send my data to add the 'match' object in the Extra to start the next activity
[image: Code from the first Activity (GameBottomActivity)]

Code I'm using to receive my data from the extras, in the second activity
[image: Code from the second Activity (GameActionsActivity]

The logs from Logcat show me at the end that the object I passed (match) has good values (on the sending side), but then, the values are wrecked (on the receiving side). It's interesting to note that the ID and the Local values are OK, but not the other ones.
[image: Logs]

Anybody would have an idea of why the object gets wrecked in the middle ?

I tried, as you saw in previous screenshots, to use the Log.d logging function with Logcat, to see the object is OK before sending it, and not OK after receiving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To those who wants the answer of how I resolved that :
In my match model class, the order of the variables when we manipule the parcel is important.

I had to set the same order of the variables, between my constructor and the parcel function :
[Contructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cnt2W.png)
[Parcel function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qeLi.png)

With that, it's working now !